# Проблема в понимании синтаксиса ( Python )

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот

Очень хочу научиться создавать бота в телеграмме, но встретила непонятный синтаксис, который никогда ранее не встречала. Пожалуйста, обьясните что это значит... Что значит этот символ собаки перед именем модуля? Не декоратор же?...

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'It works!')
```

Comment: Это именно декоратор. При получении ботом команды /start запускается функция start. То есть по сути, эта команда является вызовом этой функции.

Comment: @Pigeoncatcher, а в чем смысл использования функции-декоратора? Неужели нельзя было обойтись синтаксисом обычной функции?

Comment: @Pigeoncatcher, не понимаю этого никак...